# How to execute a shell script as input on an interactive bash pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I have a shell script `my-script.sh` like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  echo '1'
done
```

I can deploy a bash pod in Kubernetes like:

```bash
kubectl run my-shell --rm -it --image bash -- bash
```

Now, I want to execute the script on bash. How can I pass `my-script.sh` as input to bash? Something like

```bash
kubectl run my-shell --rm -it --image bash -- /bin/bash -c < my-script.sh
```

Comment: your first script can be simply `yes 1`

Comment: `kubectl run my-shell --rm -it --image bash -- /bin/bash my-script.sh` You may want to use the full path to `my-script.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `-t` to `kubectl run` (because you're reading from stdin, not a terminal) and the `-c` from bash (because you're passing the script on stdin, not as an argument):

```
$ kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --image docker.io/bash -- bash < my-script.sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
1
1
1
1
...
```